# AspectJ non-Spring annotations not intercepting adviced methods

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspectj

I wanted to use AOP-styled annotations for `@Around` advice in a non-Spring project. I was able to make up some code, but it's been giving me trouble - instead of seeing the console output as coded in the `Advice` I can only see the `SampleClass` method's printout.

Providing a minimal, reproductible example of my code. Hoping to get some hint on how to get it working. Thanks!

**Main.java**

```
package pl.bart;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SampleClass().a());
    }
}
```

**SampleClass.java**

```
package pl.bart;

public class SampleClass {

    @Annotation
    public String a() {
        return "Hello from sample class";
    }

}
```

**Annotation.java**

```
package pl.bart;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Annotation {
}
```

**Advice.java**

```
package pl.bart;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class Advice {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(Annotation)")
    public void callAt() {

    }

    @Around("callAt()")
    public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Hello from advice");
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs());
    }
}
```

**META-INF/aop.xml**

```
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="pl.bart.Advice"/>
        <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
            <include within="pl.bart.*"/>
        </weaver>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.bart</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/org/aspectj/
                        aspectjweaver/1.8.9/
                        aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are three mistakes in you project.

1.

```java
    @Pointcut("@annotation(Annotation)")
    public void callAt() {

    }
```

use fully qualified names of classes, i.e. `pl.bart.Annotation` instead of `Annotation` - it costs you nothing but saves a lot of time, in particular aspectj 1.5.4 "does not support" simple names.

2.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

aspectj does some magic with bytecode, and it is too naive to expect the library released 12 years ago supports java 17, switch to the [recent aspectj 1.9.9](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/dist/doc/README-199.html), also note you need to add `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to JVM arguments.

3.

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

if you are going to use `load time weaving` and you don't use `native aspectJ (.aj) syntax`, you do not need `aspectj-maven-plugin` - it compiles `.aj` files and performs `compile time weaving`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andrey! I have changed it to `pl.bart.Annotation`, changed versions to `1.9.9` in `pom.xml` and deleted the plugin. Despite running it with given JVM options and installing InteliJ AspectJ plugin unfortunately I'm still unable to make it work.

Comment: Also run `mvn clean package` with `maven-assembly-plugin` and attempted to run the application with `java -jar .\aspectj-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` without any success.

Comment: how do you run it? `java -jar .\aspectj-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` - where is `-javaagent:...` part?

Comment: Got it! That was by far the most helpful answer I could have. Thanks!